# Why is $\frac{n}{x}x^n = nx^{n-1}$?

Tags: calculus

I was looking at implicit differentiation proof of power rule and the final step was about this. Is $\frac{n}{x}x^n = nx^{n-1}$ a rule that I didn't know?

Comment: $\frac {x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$.

Comment: $\frac{n}{x}x^n = n\times \frac{1}{x}\times x^n = n\times x^{-1}\times x^n = n\times x^{(-1)+(n)} = nx^{n-1}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Even for such a simple question, I am grateful to you because you have commented without expecting a reward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just one of the laws of exponents.  $\frac {x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$

Answer (score 0):

You can split $\frac nx x^n$ into $n \cdot \frac {x^n}n\ \implies nx^{n-1}$